# Proving not a inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\Omega = [−1, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and consider $\Pi_2(\Omega)$.
 Prove that $<.f|g> = f(x_1)g(x_1) + f(x_2)g(x_2)$ does not define an inner product on $\Pi_2(\Omega)$
for any $x_1, x_2 \in \Omega$. 
i'm finding it difficult relating to $u,v,w$ can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please edit with Latex

Comment: unsure how to, surely its still readable. Any suggestions on how to transfer to u's and v's

Comment: What does it mean by $\Pi_2(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what you mean by $\Pi_2(\Omega)$ (especially the meaning of $2$), may I assume it means the space of all real functions with domain $\Omega$. I assume you are considering real functions because otherwise it's too trivial that the answer is it fails the conjugate symmetry requirement.

The linearity part is ok.

For positive definiteness, $<f,f>\ge 0$ is ok.

However, it fails the requirement that $<f|f>=0 \iff f=0$. Because $<f,f>=0$ only implies $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ but $f$ can be non-zero elsewhere.

Since you asked for relating it to $u,v,w$, which I suppose means the usual 3D vector space. So think about why $<u,v>=u_xv_x+u_yv_y+u_zv_z$ is a valid inner product in 3D but $<u,v>=u_xv_x+u_yv_y$ is not.